# Can you sum the bounds of two separate surfaces to bound the new summed surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

More formally, let a surface be of the form $z=f(x,y)+g(x,y)$. Let $0\leq f(x,y)\leq h(x)$ and $0\leq g(x,y) \leq k(y)$ (running out of variables!) Is it valid to say that $0\leq f(x,y)+g(x,y)\leq h(x)+k(y)$?

Comment: Well yes, obviously it is true that if $a\le A$ and $b \le B$ then $a+b\le A+B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what you gain from thinking of your functions as surfaces. Think of them as real numbers: for any given $x$, $y$ obviously $0 \leq f \leq h, \ 0\leq g \leq k \Rightarrow f + g \leq h + k$

UPD: Can't comment :(
About your example: yes, $h+k \rightarrow \infty$ at 0, but so do any bounds on $f$ and $g$ (say, $f \leq 1/x^2$), and the inequality still holds at any point.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure. One case in particular worried me. $f(x,y)=x^2/(x^4+y^4)$ and $g(x,y)=y^2/(x^4+y^4)$ which can be bounded separately, but when combined into one function, the new function cannot equal zero, it will yield the indeterminate form 0/0.